# django-oauth-toolkit error: Unable to parse query string

Tags: python, django, django-oauth-toolkit

I'm trying to access the `/o/authorize/` domain with the following parameters:
[image: Postman Parameters]

I'm redirected to login at an admin portal and once I successfully login, I get this: "Error: invalid_request. Unable to parse query string"

This is the code I'm using to generate the `code_challenge`:

```py
import random
import string
import base64
import hashlib

code_verifier = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(random.randint(43, 128)))
code_verifier = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(code_verifier.encode('utf-8'))

code_challenge = hashlib.sha256(code_verifier).digest()
code_challenge = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(code_challenge).decode('utf-8').replace('=', '')

print(fr'code verifier: {code_verifier}')
print(fr'code challenger: {code_challenge}')
```